# why does pinging in alpine always come back with dnsrsearch's ip

Tags: alpine-linux

Pinging in alpine shell would always get back a reply. for eg.

```
ping junk_junnn
64 bytes from 198.105.244.228: seq=0 ttl=37 time=0.589 ms
64 bytes from 198.105.244.228: seq=1 ttl=37 time=1.428 ms
```

Is there a way to find if the given string is not a valid network resource other than getting reply from the dnrsearch.com

Answer (score 0):

This is not a normal behaviour on Alpine Linux. It may be caused by some incorrect configuration of your system or network.

I encountered same behaviour some time ago, but don’t remember what was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You are pinging an unknown host which is being forwarded out to your normal DNS resolver. An external DNS resolver is returning one of their own IP's for the unknown address.

This is normally done by your ISP or [sometimes the company that hosts the top level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record#Registries.2FISPs) to provide their own web site to direct web users somewhere (normally with paid ads/search).

Use Google's 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 DNS servers or someone like [OpenDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDNS) to avoid your resolver returning the false positives. There's not much you can do about TLD's doing other than [running a custom DNS server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record#Ignoring_wildcards_from_others).